# Xcode 10 "This App could not be installed" every other time when running unit tests

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xcode10

Ever since updating to Xcode 10 I have to run my unit tests twice in order to get them to actually run.

The first time I get the "This app could not be installed at this time: Failed to load Info.plist from bundle path ....".

The second time I run it executes just fine.

It looks like the first time it runs it's just trying to clean or reinstall the app from the simulator - about half of the time when I click "Ok" on the alert the app is removed from the simulator.

Running the actual app in the simulator works fine every time.

Has anyone else seen this & is there some new Unit Test configuration I've missed?

Comment: I'm seeing this as well after installing Xcode 10